# Repeating definitons of variables

Tags: functions, variable-definitions, variable

I have the piece of definitions

```
y = 1;
x = 2;
n = 2;
a := (y^(x - 1) + n)/(y^(x - 1) + y^(x - 2))
```

I want to keep defining y as a by doing:

```
y = 1;
x = 2;
n = 2;
a := (y^(x - 1) + n)/(y^(x - 1) + y^(x - 2))
a
y=a;
a
y=a;
a
y=a;
a
```

etc. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I am not sure I follow the question. But may be what you want is `Clear[a]; y = a` and this gives `a` and not `3/2` ?

Comment: no no, I want 3/2 as the answer. I just want it to print the answers 3/2, 7/5, 17/12, 41/29...

Comment: But the code you wrote prints: 3/2, 7/5, 17/12,...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> no no, I want 3/2 as the answer. I just want it to print the answers
> 3/2, 7/5, 17/12, 41/29...

One of 10 possible ways

```
y = 1;
x = 2;
n = 2;
a := (y^(x - 1) + n)/(y^(x - 1) + y^(x - 2))

Last@Reap@Do[
   Sow[a];
   y = a
   , {m, 10}
   ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or if you prefer shorter code

```
Flatten[{a; y = a} & /@ Range[10]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
y = 1;
x = 2;
n = 2;

NestList[(#^(x - 1) + n)/(#^(x - 1) + #^(x - 2)) &, y, 6]
```

---

**EDIT**

If the same definition must be used and kept, then define:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
y = 1;
x = 2;
n = 2;
a[y_] := (y^(x - 1) + n)/(y^(x - 1) + y^(x - 2))


NestList[a[#] &, 1, 6]
```

which is redundant. The more standard idiom would be:

```
NestList[a, 1, 6]
```

---

Result:

> {1, 3/2, 7/5, 17/12, 41/29, 99/70, 239/169}

Answer (score 4):

Following Syed's idea, another way to do this is to use `FoldList`:

```
With[{x = 2, y = 1, n = 2}, FoldList[(#^(x - 1) + n)/(#^(x - 1) + #^(x - 2)) &, y, Range[6]]]

(*{1, 3/2, 7/5, 17/12, 41/29, 99/70, 239/169}*)
```

Also, you can use `FixedPointList`:

```
With[{x = 2, y = 1, n = 2}, FixedPointList[(#^(x - 1) + n)/(#^(x - 1) + #^(x - 2)) &, y, 6]]

(*{1, 3/2, 7/5, 17/12, 41/29, 99/70, 239/169}*)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
x = 2; n = 2;
```

The general solution is

```
Clear[y]; 
y[m_] = RSolveValue[{y[
      m] == (y[m - 1]^(x - 1) + n)/(y[m - 1]^(x - 1) + y[m - 1]^(x - 2)), 
    y[0] == 1}, y[m], m] // Simplify

(* ((1 - Sqrt[2])^m (-2 + Sqrt[2]) + (1 + Sqrt[2])^
  m (2 + Sqrt[2]))/(-(1 - Sqrt[2])^(1 + m) + (1 + Sqrt[2])^(1 + m)) *)

y /@ Range[0, 8] // Simplify

(* {1, 3/2, 7/5, 17/12, 41/29, 99/70, 239/169, 577/408, 1393/985} *)

ymax = 6;

Show[
 Plot[Re@y[m], {m, 0, ymax}, PlotRange -> All],
 DiscretePlot[y[m], {m, 0, ymax},
  Filling -> None,
  PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

The real function passing through the points is

```
y2[m_] = Re[y[m]] // ComplexExpand // Simplify

(* ((-1 + Sqrt[2])^(2 m) (-4 + 3 Sqrt[2]) - (1 + Sqrt[2])^(
    2 m) (4 + 3 Sqrt[2]))/((-1 + Sqrt[2])^(
    2 m) (-3 + 2 Sqrt[2]) - (1 + Sqrt[2])^(2 m) (3 + 2 Sqrt[2]) - 
   2 Cos[m π]) *)

And @@ Table[y[m] == y2[m] // Simplify, {m, 0, 20}]

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 3):

The formula is a recursion, and so can be written:

```
Clear[y]; x = 2; n = 2; y[1] = 1;
y[k_] := y[k] = (y[k - 1]^(x - 1) + n)/(y[k - 1]^(x - 1) + y[k - 1]^(x - 2))
```

Then you can get individual values as

```
{y[1], y[2], y[3]}
```

or get 10 at once:

```
y /@ Range[10]
```

Comment: This properly addresses the problem.